# Open file from NERDtree in specific window (or last active)

Tags: vim, nerdtree

In VIM I've got 4 windows opened and a NERD tree like this:
[image: screenshot]
So, whenever I try to open the file from NERD, it's opened in first buffer (topleft pos). Sometimes in other buffers.
Is there a way to open a file in bottom right position ? Mb there are workarounds ?
Maybe I can force NERDtree to open file in last active window ? At the moment, it doesn't work this way :(

UPD: It looks like the problem is in hidden buffers.
When the buffer was opened in one window, and then replaced by another - if you try to open the very first in another window, you'll get it opened in the window it was opened in the very first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using NERD tree 4.1.0 on Vim 7.2 and NERDTree does open files in the last active window by default.

From the docs:

> Default key: o
>
> Map option: NERDTreeMapActivateNode
>
> Applies to: files and directories.
>
> If a file node is selected, it is opened in the previous window.

But hitting enter when the file is selected has the same effect.

Comment: For some reason, in the latest version of NERDTree this behavior no longer works -- it always seems to jump to an already open buffer of that file rather than opening in the previous window. Has anyone else noticed this?

Comment: I noticed that installing [golden-ratio](https://github.com/roman/golden-ratio) will break this behavior. @AaronGibralter